# Android - prevent lock screen FaceWidget "Music controller" from overriding my music player app notification

Tags: android, notifications, lockscreen, android-mediasession

I tried with no luck to add custom commands to music controller on lock screen and AOD screen, thus I decided to make a custom notification (at least for the lock screen). The problem is, that if user has a FaceWidget (settings > Lock Screen > FaceWiget > "Music controller" turned on, then it takes over and displays 3 button control instead of my notification. How do I prevent that?

[Example of what I want to disable for my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eyTd.jpg)

I use exoPlayer with MesiaSessionCompat in androidx.